# Elasticsearch crashes with AccessDeniedException when providing new data.path

Tags: elasticsearch

I updated the `data.path` entry in `elasticsearch.yml` to point at a new location. However, upon trying to restart Elastic, I now get the following error:

```
Starting elasticsearch: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/etc/lib/stuff)
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/lib
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:227)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:203)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:184)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:196)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

For the sake of debugging, I'm trying to move the data.path from the default of `var/lib/elasticsearch` to `/var/lib/stuff`.

As far as I can tell, the user, group, and permissions match across these two directories:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/

drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Jan 11 10:50 elasticsearch
...
drwxr-xr-x 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Jan 13 10:54 stuff
...
```

So why does Elastic throw an `AccessDenied` Exception?

If I remove my custom `data.path` it goes back to working without issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: The error mention `/etc/lib/stuff` not `/var/lib/stuff`. + the setting is called `path.data` not `data.path` (but I guess this is just a typo). Apparently, the problem is that the `elasticsearch` user cannot create a new folder in `etc/lib`